# Advancing multiple iterators into the same stringstream

Tags: c++, io, stream, iterator

Please check out this code snippet

```cpp
  std::istringstream s("abc");
  std::istreambuf_iterator<char> i1(s), i2(s);
  std::cout<< "i1 returns "<<*i1<<'\n'
           << "i2 returns "<<*i2<<'\n';
  ++i1;
  std::cout<<"after incrementing i1, but not i2\n"
           <<"i1 returns "<<*i1<<'\n'
           <<"i2 returns "<<*i2<<'\n';
  ++i2; // this makes the apparent value of *i2 to jump from 'a' to 'c'
  std::cout << "after incrementing i2, but not i1\n"
            << "i1 returns " << *i1 << '\n'
            << "i2 returns " << *i2 << '\n';
```

and i got the output like

```
a
a

b
b

c
c
```

which is totally different from what I expected, because i1 & i2 are two different iterators.

Anyone do me a favor?

Comment: What did you expect?

Comment: Also, your comment in the code implies that you got "b a" the second time, but your output has "b b", and is missing the other strings you outputted. Please attach the real output from the snippet you gave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator):

> `std::istreambuf_iterator` is a single-pass input iterator that reads successive characters from the `std::basic_streambuf` object for which it was constructed.

The important part here is the **single-pass** characteristics: once a value has been read, you cannot go back and read it again. Recall that you can use `std::istreambuf_iterator` for `std::cin` for example. If you read from `std::cin` in your program, this means you might interactively type in characters - there is no going back (you have to save the bytes in a `std::string` or similar to achieve that).

Now when creating multiple iterators that refer to the identical stream object, advancing one means reading a character - which is seen by all iterators. This is due to the **single-pass** nature of the iterator, see also the documentation for [operator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator/operator*):

> Reads a single character by calling sbuf_->sgetc() where sbuf_ is the stored pointer to the stream buffer.

Clearly, all iterator instances share the state that is used by the dereferencing operator.